# Permissions using Samba Linux-to-Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, samba

Basically I'm having trouble with permissions being inconsistent between `Samba` and the local file system.  Locally I set the file permission to `-r--r--r--` with `chmod 444 textfile.txt` and confirm these settings with `ls -al`.  Then I do a Samba mount.  If I look at the same file's permissions via Samba what I see is `-rwxr-xr-x` or `-r-xr-xr-x`, but not `-r--r--r--`.  This happens even when a Linux box is looking at himself via `Samba`.

I'm required to use Samba between Linux VMs using various vendors and versions (as well as Windows VMs, but this note is about Linux only.)  I'm testing with `CentOS 7 & 8`, `RedHat 7 & 8`, `OpenSUSE 15` and `SUSE 15`.  I get similar results from all permutations of these Linux distros.  The only one that works correctly is `CentOS8` as a Samba client to `OpenSUSE15` as the Samba server--this is the only case where `Samba`'s displayed permissions match the permissions displayed locally.

Yes, `NFS` would be easier, but I must get this working via `Samba`.  Note that this is just a test environment--some of the things below reflect my attempts to simplify the environment.  Once I get things working properly, I'll tighten up security.

Here is my setup and steps:

In `smb.conf`, I've shared the entire drive as `C`.  I've already added root to the `SMB` users and assigned a password.

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    wins support = yes
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups
    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw
[C]
    Path = /
    Browseable = yes
    Writeable = yes
    only guest = no
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
    Public = yes
    Guest ok = yes
```

I'm using the same VMs, steps and files, with all permutations.  With all VMs, I'm logged to a bash shell as root via PuTTY.

On the Server machine, create a folder with a text file, assign permissions and verify.

```
mkdir /temp
cd /temp
cp /etc/samba/smb.conf /temp/smb.conf
    It could be any file, I'm using smb.conf as an example.
chmod 444 smb.conf
ll smb.conf
    -r--r--r-- 1 root root <size> <date> smb.conf
```

From the Client machine, perform a mount command and look at the file permissions via `Samba`:

```
mkdir /mnt/test
mount -t cifs //svrname/c /mnt/test -o username=root,password=mypasswd
    In the simplest loopback case, svrname is 'localhost'.
ll /mnt/test/temp/smb.conf
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root <size> <date> smb.conf
```

I need the `Samba` view of permissions for that file to match the local permissions, like this:

```
ll /mnt/test/temp/smb.conf
    -r--r--r-- 1 root root <size> <date> smb.conf
```

However other than that one case mentioned above, I always see `-rwxr-xr-x` or `-r-xr-xr-x`.

I've tried all sorts of things but with no luck.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Samba's Unix extensions are enabled. E.g.,:

```
[global]
unix extensions = yes
⋮
```

otherwise, the protocol only supports Windows permissions (ACLs), not Unix permissions. (I thought yes was the default, but maybe the distro changed that).

Similarly, the mount needs to enable them as well, the option is `unix` there.
Also, you may want to set `guest ok = no` to make sure you're actually authenticating, and not accidentally getting guest.

Comment: Although `unix extensions` is not in the [smb.conf manual](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) it's definitely accepted.  Looks like `testparm` primarily displays options that are not using their default values.  If true then  `unix extensions` seems to default to yes.

Comment: The [mount.cifs man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) does not list `unix` as an option, and it definitely throws an error when running `testparm`.  There is only a `nounix` option.

Comment: I definitely set `guest ok = no` as suggested.

I tried all sorts of permutations of `unix extensions` in smb.conf and `nounix` in the mount command.  No improvement.

I noticed another post yesterday speculating that the `x` bits I'm seeing might be the result of some confusion with the DOS archive bit.  However this does not explain why the `w` bits appear where they should not.

Comment: @Jeff Apparently the `unix` option is new (see, e.g., https://manpages.debian.org/testing/cifs-utils/mount.cifs.8.en.html has it, search for `|unix|`) ... but its been the default for a while. So it should be on. And you don't seem to have `force create mode` or similar, so this is odd.